# What is the alternative of PL/Java for PostgreSQL 11 and 12?

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, postgresql-12, enterprisedb, pljava

Understand from: https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/user-guide/11/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_Guide.1.80.html

that PL/Java is deprecated in Advanced Server 11 and will be unavailable in server versions 12 or later.

May I know:

1. What is the recommended replacement for PL/Java in PostgreSQL12?
2. For my existing UDF in PostgreSQL 9.6.x, etc., which is using the PL/Java, how could I move over to PostgreSQL 12?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

---

Edit: Come to think of it, there was an issue reported back in September 2020 ([PL/Java issue 260](https://github.com/tada/pljava/issues/260)) about failing to build against EDB PostgreSQL 11. It turned out that EDB had made an API-breaking change to upstream PostgreSQL, by changing an API function and leaving behind only a macro with the old name, instead of a (possibly `inline`-qualified) wrapper that could be addressed.

That ended up requiring an EDB-specific workaround to be shipped in PL/Java, and that fix has been included since **PL/Java 1.6.0** and since **PL/Java 1.5.6**, which both were released in October 2020.

---

I am sorry that I did not see this question earlier.

I maintain PL/Java, and I have had no notice from EDB concerning why they have deprecated it. Perhaps they are simply no longer providing a binary package prebuilt by them.

I know of PL/Java in use with PostgreSQL 12 and 13. I believe that to build it from source for use with EDB, it should be built with Visual Studio, following [these instructions](https://tada.github.io/pljava/build/buildmsvc.html).

If you are able to learn anything more from EDB about the deprecation, or if you have any difficulty building from source, please feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/tada/pljava/issues). Thanks!